# Apache Camel tesing. Remove RoutePolicy

Tags: java, apache-camel, apache-zookeeper

Here is Apache Camel route:

```
ZooKeeperRoutePolicy routePolicy = new ZooKeeperRoutePolicy("zookeeper:localhost:2181/fuse-example/routePolicy", 1);
from("file:camelInpit").routeId("systemARoute")
                .routePolicy(routePolicy)
                .log(LoggingLevel.ERROR, "Starting route")
                [...]
```

I want to remove routePolicy in my tests since there is no ZooKeeper in test environment, but this is not as easy as it seems

```
    context.getRouteDefinition("systemARoute").adviceWith(context, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            replaceFromWith("direct:aaa");
            weaveByType(RouteDefinition.class).selectIndex(1).remove();
        }
    });
```

`weaveById("policy")` and setting the id `routePolicy(...).id("policy")` does not help.

How can I dynamically remove `RoutePolicies` while testing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the original route and set its route policies to null

```
    context.getRouteDefinition("systemARoute").adviceWith(context, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            getOriginalRoute().setRoutePolicies(null);
        }
    });
```

But we should maybe add fluent DSL builders for this to make it stand out?

Answer (score 3):

Is it not possible to do something like that?

```
from("file:camelInpit").routeId("systemARoute")
                .choice()
                  .when(prodEnvironmentExpression)
                    .routePolicy(routePolicy)
                  .endChoice()
                .end()
                .log(LoggingLevel.ERROR, "Starting route")
```

Comment: I am using `RouteBuilder`. Is it possible to pass parameters from tests to `RouteBuilder`s?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't exactly understand what you mean.

Comment: As I understand, `prodEnvironmentExpression` should be some config parameter which is automatically enabled when tests start. How can I pass parameters from tests to route to make this expression evaluate to true?

Comment: If you have a web application for example you can use a vm argument or an environment variable for the prod/test environment. With the PredicateBuilder for example you can create expressions of "normal" values coming from outside the RouteBuilder.

Comment: I run this app inside OSGI container, so JVM arguments are not very pleasant to use solution

Comment: Is defining a variable in your web.xml possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you bind it to the context you can easily make a mock of the policy in your tests by using, where myPolicy is a mock or a policy that does nothing.

Even easier if you make an abstract MyCamelTestSupport which overides that and then all your tests which needs to mock it extends MyCamelTestSupport

```
@Override
protected JndiRegistry createRegistry() throws Exception {
    JndiRegistry jndi = super.createRegistry();
    jndi.bind("myPolicy", myPolicy);
    return jndi;
}
```

Comment: How `ZooKeeperRoutePolicy` will be created in production environment? As you can see currently I create it inside the code. Am I supposed to use `camelContext.getRegistry()` and bind my policy to Camel JNDI registry?

Comment: Depending on how you are creating it, as a standalone, it would be main.bind() and if going for a ServletContextListener you would need to create a SimpleRegistry (put) or InitialContext (bind) and create a create a new DefaultCamelContext(arg) where arg would be the SimpleRegistry or InitialContext.

Comment: I am running Camel inside Apache Karaf OSGI container using Blueprint.

Comment: Maybe the same way other beans are created, <bean id="myPolicy" class="org.apache.camel.component.zookeeper.policy.ZooKeeperRoutePolicy"> <property name="uri" value="zookeeper:localhost:2181/fuse-example/routePolicy"/><property name="enabledCount" value="1" /> </bean>