How to Test Apache Camel Route with RoutePolicy without Modifying Route Code?
I am working on testing an Apache Camel route that utilizes a RoutePolicy. The route code is as follows:
from("direct:test")
            .routeId(IMPORT_AGENTS_REFERENTIAL)
            .noAutoStartup().shutdownRunningTask(ShutdownRunningTask.CompleteAllTasks)
            .routePolicy(routeStartStopPolicy)
            .setHeader(EsbExchangeProperty.EXTENSION, constant("test"))
            .to("log:test2");
    }

Here is my test class:

@CamelSpringBootTest
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(
        properties = { "camel.springboot.name=customName" }
)
class Test{

    @Autowired
    ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

    @Autowired
    CamelContext camelContext;


    @Autowired
    static RoutePolicy routeStartStopPolicy;
    @EndpointInject("mock:log")
    MockEndpoint mockEndpoint;
    
    @Test
    public void shouldAutowireProducerTemplate() {
        assertNotNull(producerTemplate);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldSetCustomName() {
        assertEquals("customName", producerTemplate.getCamelContext().getName());
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldInjectEndpoint() throws Exception {
        
        adviceWith(camelContext, "ROUTE 1", a -> {
            a.replaceFromWith("direct:modifiedStart");
            a.weaveByToUri("log:test2").replace().to("mock:log");
        });

        camelContext.start();
        camelContext.getRouteController().startRoute("ROUTE 1");
        mockEndpoint.expectedBodiesReceived("Hello 1");  
        mockEndpoint.setExpectedMessageCount(1);
        mockEndpoint.expectedHeaderReceived(EsbExchangeProperty.EXTENSION,"json");

        producerTemplate.sendBody("direct:modifiedStart", "Hello 1");
        
        mockEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
        
    }
}

I believe this issue is related to the RoutePolicy. If I comment out the routePolicy(routeStartStopPolicy) line in the route configuration, the test runs successfully.
I want to test the route without modifying the actual route code. How can I resolve this issue and properly inject a RoutePolicy for testing?.
I've tried to find a method in Apache Camel that allows me to mock the RoutePolicy, but I haven't been able to find one.

Would you like to just remove the RoutePolicy during test? Then you can try to set it to null. Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29891368/apache-camel-tesing-remove-routepolicy
